# Some my users complain that my alarm manager does not work. Why?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

Recently, I released a text based game in which main hero is offline for some times ( nearly 15 minutes). However, nearly 10 users out of 100 complained that the main hero never comes online. I have following Alarm Receiver class:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
Context cont;
Notification noti;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    WakeLocker.acquire(context);
    cont = context;
    context.sendBroadcast(new Intent("MESSAGE"));
    writeWaitTimeAlert("0");
    if(!isAppForground(context))
        notifyMe();
    WakeLocker.release();
}

public void writeWaitTimeAlert(String str) {

    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = cont.openFileOutput("timeBoolean.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fileOutputStream.write(str.getBytes());
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream);
        osw.flush();
        osw.close();
        fileOutputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public boolean isAppForground(Context mContext) {

    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> tasks = am.getRunningTasks(1);
    if (!tasks.isEmpty()) {
        ComponentName topActivity = tasks.get(0).topActivity;
        if (!topActivity.getPackageName().equals(mContext.getPackageName())) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
public void notifyMe() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(cont, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(cont, 0, intent, 0);
    noti = new Notification.Builder(cont)
            .setTicker("My app")
            .setContentTitle("Message")
            .setContentText("Hello!")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_message)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).getNotification();
    noti.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) cont.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nm.notify(0, noti);


}
```

}

And I have setAlarm in another class named "Playground.class":

```
public void setAlarm(long time) {


    Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Offline!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("alarmId", REQUEST_CODE);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, REQUEST_CODE, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() +
                    time * 1000, pendingIntent);

}
```

Please help me or suggest me other ways to solve it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your setAlarm method should work as a BroadcastReceiver class. Let send some broadcast from your Service/Activity class.

```
Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(this, TimeBroadcast.class);
sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
```

And put this code into your BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class TimeBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {

public TimeBroadcast() {
}

public TimeBroadcast(Context context) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    int repeatTime = 10 * 1000 * 60;
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, TimeBroadcast.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis() + repeatTime, pendingIntent);
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, YOUR_CLASS);
    //pass values, actions, flags, whatever you want and send your Intent where you want
}
```

}

This code will send an Intent to your Service/Activity class delayed by time sets in the AlarmManager.set method. When as Intent will come to your class, you can handle some action such like warning message or disconnect afk users/heroes.

Comment: Do I need to write setAlarm method in the BroadReceiver class?

Comment: Why not? I think, in your case best way is remove actually code from setAlarm method, and make it to sending broadcasts with extra value to BroadcastReceiver such like my above code. Next get it from intent and use  like dynamic param. And finally, send broadcast from class like TimeBroadcast to your AlarmReceiver class. This will execute your code inside AlarmReceiver delayed by time interval passed in sendBroadcast Intent.

Comment: I want to learn why my onReceive method not triggering? Do some android phones kill my Alarm Manager? What is wrong with it? If I implement as you said, does it guarantee running code?

Comment: I debugged your setAlarm method. Your date, returned by SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), is 1970.01.03 04:12. Try to use System.getCurrentTimeInMillis(). Second thing, where are you calling your setAlarm method? You have PendingIntent.getBroadcast(), I'm not sure, but it may wait for broadcast message, there's available another methods such like PendingIntent.getActivity(), PendingIntent.getService(). When I changed this two things, your code works for me.

Comment: So you want me change set() to alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis() + time*1000, pendingIntent);